# How to print special characters in Athena/Presto

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I'm looking for a way to print tab separated values in aws Athena/presto. The following query doesn't do it:

```
select 'fielf1\tfield2'
```

which gives (unsurprisingyl)

```
field1\tfield2
```

while I would like

```
field1    field2
```

where the two fields are separated by a tab character.

EDIT: The "standard" syntax proposed by Piotr Findeisen:

```
SELECT U&'field1\0009field2'
```

Returns:

```
Your query has the following error(s):

Queries of this type are not supported (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: [...])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, a possible solution is:

```
select 'field1'||chr(9)||'field2'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT U&'field1\0009field2'
```

See more examples at https://trino.io/docs/current/language/types.html#varchar

Comment: This syntax doesn't work on aws Athena, I've edited the question

Comment: That's weird. Athena is based on Presto .172 (April 2017) and I believe we had this syntax already back then.

Comment: Works for me. `aws athena start-query-execution --query-string "select U&'foo\0009bar'"` results in `foo bar`. Using `Athena engine version 3`